# Can we get MathJax here?

Tags: feature-request

While there's a lot of opinion and intuition to gardening, a good gardener is also very good at math. Horticulture is a science, and it would be very nice to clean up [answers like this](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/a/13872/3535) with some nice formatting.

If you don't know what MathJax is, take a look at [this tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on Meta Mathematics SE.

Comment: 1. Why does a good gardener have to be good at math? 2. Agriculture is off-topic here; see the [help/on-topic]. 3. You'll need to provide more evidence of need than a single post.

Comment: @Niallc, [Agriculture, also called farming or husbandry, is the cultivation of animals, plants, fungi, and other life forms for food, fiber, biofuel, medicinals and other products used to sustain and enhance human life.](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Agriculture), I seriously don't know what else you would call gardening other than small scale agriculture, so I would challenge that, but will take the time to write a separate post. I personally believe the scope do this site is part of its problem.

Comment: A good gardener is good at math. Do you know anyone around here who wouldn't test the soil prior to planting in a new location or if they were having some sort of issue? I have a full two pages in a notebook dedicated to figuring out what type and how much fertilizer I needed. I'm not going to spend a ton of time aimlessly looking through posts to find more examples. It's obviously a good idea to format it nicely.

Comment: @ckuhn203 You may be looking for the word **Horticulture**: `the art or practice of garden cultivation and management.` *synonyms:* gardening, landscaping, cultivation; Versus **Agriculture**: `the science or practice of farming, including cultivation of the soil for the growing of crops and the rearing of animals to provide food, wool, and other products.` *synonyms*: farming, cultivation, tillage, tilling, husbandry

Comment: OOPs, why'd I use preformatted text?

Comment: Thank you. Can we focus on the actual request now @NiallC.? And perhaps remove irrelevant comments?

Comment: @J.Musser did you use `backquotes`? (this character: `)

Comment: @Philip Possibly.

Answer (score 4):

MathJax is a pretty substantial client side plugin and should *only* be activated on sites where a substantial number of questions and answers require it.

It's pretty darn rare for us to need mathematical equations and representations in our questions. I'd recommend embedding images (as well as a textual representation if you could), of chemical formulas or equations where you feel like MathJax would have been a better tool.

There's no need for MathJax here.

Comment: +1 I agree, "There's no need for MathJax here".

Answer (score 1):

This strikes me as an edge case where it would not be used by the majority of users who ask and answer questions.

Stack Exchange has always seemed to design to the "less is more" theory of design and the result is a fairly simple interface.

In order to make a case for this added feature I would have to see more than one post where it would be useful.